# Menu inside menu in Matlab

Tags: matlab, menu, matlab-gui

I have created a menu with different options using order 'menu'. The problem is, that I want to click one of that options and make another menu show in screen with another set of options. How can I make this kind of nested menu structure?

My code:

```
q=menu ('What point?:','opt1','opt2');
switch q
    case 'opt1'
        q1=menu('What subpoint?:','opt11','opt12');
        switch q1 
            case 'opt11'
            case 'opt12'
        end 
    case 'opt2'
        q2=menu('What subpoint?:','opt21','opt22');
         switch q2 
             case 'opt21'
             case 'opt22'
         end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine, except that the returned choice by `menu` is numeric, not the option strings. So you should use `case 1` rather than `case 'opt1'`.

A good practice for `switch` is to include `otherwise` block, like

```
switch q
    case 1
        % do opt1
    case 2
        % do opt2
    otherwise
        disp(q)
        error('Invalid option')
end
```

Then you will know it goes to `otherwise` block due to some error in your case.

Comment: Really useful! Thank you so much for your help!! :)) . Now it works perfectly!